# Why doesn't `dialog` display the menu (but accepts acceptance) when started through a command substitution expression?

Tags: bash, dialog

I want to, from a bash shell script, present the user with a menu of choices to pick from. The selection should then be stored in an environment variable for further use later.

If I run from the command line:

```
dialog \
    --backtitle "Make a choice" \
    --menu "Take a pick" \
    10 40 3 \
    choice1 "First choice" \
    choice2 "Second choice"
```

then everything works fine; I get the menu that I want, and `choice1` or `choice2` is printed back at me. However, if instead I run:

```
SELECTION=$( dialog \
    --backtitle "Make a choice" \
    --menu "Take a pick" \
    10 40 3 \
    choice1 "First choice" \
    choice2 "Second choice" \
)
```

then it no longer works the way I want to.

- No menu is displayed, although (as far as I can tell) `dialog` exits when I press Enter
- When I exit the non-displayed menu by pressing Enter, the tag of the selection appears on the terminal rather than being stored into $SELECTION

I have tried adding `2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout, in case it really was being printed to stderr instead. The only noticable effect of that is that now, *nothing* is returned, either from the command substitution expression *or* printed to the terminal.

On my system, `dialog` is `cdialog` 1.1-20120215. The `dialog` man page says about `--menu` that *On exit the tag of the chosen menu entry will be printed on dialog's output.* This seems like it should work fine with something like the above, but it doesn't for me.

**I want** the menu to be displayed, allowing the user to pick between the available choices, and when the user accepts, the tag (for example, `choice2`) for the selected choice to be stored in the environment variable $SELECTION. If the user cancels, there should be clear indication of that (ideally, $SELECTION would be undefined or a zero-length string).

**How can I do that?** What piece of the puzzle am I missing?

Solutions suggesting alternatives to `dialog` are also acceptable, as long as they present a nice menu to choose from and ideally the software suggested isn't too exotic (availability in the Debian Stable `main` repository is a requirement).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with the `--stdout` option:

```
$ SELECTION=$( dialog --stdout \
    --backtitle "Make a choice" \
    --menu "Take a pick" \
    10 40 3 \
    choice1 "First choice" \
    choice2 "Second choice" \
)
```